# Faster SQL results on webpage (Python 3.6, Flask, Pymssql)

Tags: python, flask, datatables, pymssql

Right now I have a little web app I made using Python, Flask, and Pymssql. One of the search functions returns all results in the database (only 1500 or so). The results are displayed in a table and it takes quite a while to render all of the results on the page, so I thought I would look into something where there is page numbers and a 'results per page' option. I set it up using DataTables 1.10.5. The issue is that when you search it still takes a few seconds, loads all 1500 results, and then formats it with pages and page numbers.

Im looking for a way to display 50 or so results very quickly and maybe load the rest in the background? Or query the server for 50 more when you press next?

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Flask SQLAlchemy Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103585/python-flask-sqlalchemy-pagination)

Comment: So I would need to change my SQL plugin to SQLAlchemy to use this Pagination tool?

Comment: Here is another way to implement too [select-records-incrementally-in-mysql-and-save-to-csv-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088768/select-records-incrementally-in-mysql-and-save-to-csv-in-python)